# .htaccess rule redirects all urls to the same location

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I am trying to modify one redirect rule but it is not working quite as I want it to. Maybe someone can look into it and advice what needs to be corrected.

I have this rule:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/$ /page.php?id=$1 [L]
```

The rule redirects `www.site.com/page.php?id=one` to `www.site.com/one/` which is what I need to do.

However, the same rule redirects all other pages like `www.site.com/about-us/` to `www.site.com/page.php?id=`.

What needs to be changed in the rule to only redirect the page I want to and not all the others?

Answer (score 0):

You can restrict your rule:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(one|two|three)/$ /page.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: this would not work since the `$id` can be any combination of letters and numbers

Comment: You asked: **What needs to be changed in the rule to only redirect the page I want to** which means you already know name of pages to be redirected. Above is just an example on how to include only **known pages** to be rewritten.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I could think of is to insert insert an identifier key either in URL which you want to ignore or rewrite.

e.g. below code will rewrite `http://www.example.com/one-1/` by `http://www.example.com/page.php?id=one-1`

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-_]+)-([0-9]+)/$ /page.php?id=$1 [L]
```

Comment: this is what I intend to do in case there is no other option. Decided to ask first since i'd like to keep the URL as clean as possible.

Comment: In that case the other option is to use hard-coded rewrite conditions (without regular  expressions).